# Crystal Reports Suppressing Page Header & Footer

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am having some minor challenges with supressing the page header and footer.  I am using the report footer on a purchase order format to create a page of terms and conditions.  When the purchase order has more than 1 line item i can supress the header using the "onlastrecord" line in the report,  However when the order only has 1 line item the page header and footer is supressed on the first page where the item appears but also on the last page.

Any ideas on how to solve this?